# PHP setup for web services on Windows 7

Tags: php, web-services

I want to build webservices in php.

I understand I'll need a server but I'm not sure if I should go with apache24 or wamp.

I also understand I'll need some SQL database but not sure which one.
I can't find a source that will help me figure the installations and the basics of beginning php web service development.

Comment: Yeah, you can google WAMP. There is a lot of turorials there.

Answer (score 0):

While you will get mixed answers, I use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), and haven't has any issues. Basic instructions are right on the home page.

WAMP = Windows, Apache2, PHP and a MySQL ~ so it's pretty much all you need to get started.

There are also tutorials that you can find, by simply typing in "Wamp install instructions" into Google search.

~

Re: "the basics of beginning php web service development."

See: https://www.w3schools.com/php/

You can also find sql stuff on w3schools

Answer (score 0):

As Kastener said, you might get mixed answers, after all it's personal taste and experience. As you have said windows 7, I am  answering. I am using XAMPP on my windows 7 32bits and 64bits laptops. XAMPP comes with Apache Server, PHP and mySql packed in it and a hassle-free windows installer. Only minor settings to be done. I find easy to configure and use